# Unresponsive Web Scripts Cause Ubuntu to Stall

Tags: crash, browser

At least I THINK this is the problem. So I'm basically going about my business with various tasks when Ubuntu simply grinds to a crawl. It may take about ten minutes for normal behaviour to resume. I sometimes have to use htop to kill my running browsers. Every time this happens it seems there's an unresponsive web page in one of the browsers.

Any ideas on how to stop this behaviour? If there's an unresponsive web page it shouldn't cause the whole system to stall...

Comment: I meant to type "Ubuntu."

Comment: Please specify which web browser you are using. If you are using Google Chrome or Chromium. You can press `Shift+Esc` to open the task manager to see which tab (or tabs) is hogging your resource (including CPU and memory) and trouble shoot the problem.

Comment: Then just edit your question to fix that.

Comment: I don't think it's browser specific - i.e. it happens with Chrome and Firefox. The problem is so bad that I'm barely able to do anything, even open the task manager.

Comment: Can you specify more about when does it happen? It happen righter after open chrome or firefox, or it happen after you open some website, or it happen after a long time put as idle. Add this additional information to your question could help to sort out the problem.

Comment: Btw, I want to add this post as comment rather than solution at the beginning, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I can't remember it ever happening when I start up the browsers. It's generally in response to some action performed in the browser, but it may happen with the browsers running in the background.

Comment: I have more specific information about this problem. It happens in all browsers as a response to a specific web script. I can replicate this by going to alibaba dot com and doing a search or opening a chat window. It almost crashes the computer. It's not specific to that site - it's the script. I briefly saw a message in Firefox relating to a 3-letter acronym (some kind of script) - but I can't remember the acronym. Any thoughts, people?

Comment: This problem seems particular to Firefox. I think it has something to do with entering text in chat windows or forms. Force-quitting Firefox - if at all possible - normally resolves the problem.